# How to config ftps user for wordpress on linux centos 6.9 port 22 ftps(ssl)

Tags: linux, wordpress

my wordpress directory /var/www/html/web/wordpress

I can not install plugin&theme wordpress.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner. i will read doc. now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

add this in your wp-config.php file and check